# Move group of files into subdirectory

Tags: bash, mv

I want to move some ssh keys into a backup file. Specifically, I want to move `id_rsa*` into `key_backups/`, a subdirectory of .ssh. `mv id_rsa* key_backup/` gives me back

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
   mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

But I feel like what I'm doing is of the second variety...

#### EDIT

```
total 64
drwx------  11 chrismaddox  staff   374 Apr 30 14:12 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 56 chrismaddox  staff  1904 May  5 11:05 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 chrismaddox  staff    61 Apr 10 13:11 config
-rw-------   1 chrismaddox  staff  1766 Mar 15 14:07 github_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 chrismaddox  staff   393 Mar 15 14:07 github_rsa.pub
-rw-------   1 chrismaddox  staff   668 Mar 16 14:11 id_dsa
-rw-r--r--   1 chrismaddox  staff   623 Mar 16 14:11 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------   1 chrismaddox  staff  1679 Mar 16 14:28 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 chrismaddox  staff  1679 May  5 13:00 id_rsa.pub
drwxr-xr-x   2 chrismaddox  staff    68 Mar  8 16:38 key_backup
-rw-r--r--   1 chrismaddox  staff  3188 Apr 30 15:36 known_hosts
```

Comment: still getting the same output :(

Comment: Your original command should work. Can you do a `ls -la` of your directory?

Comment: edited my original post with my directory

Comment: why do you try move to `keygen`, when the directory is `key_backup`? try `mv file* dir/.`

Comment: sorry, mistyped it. I am entering key_backup/id_rsa*

Comment: You should _not_ be entering `key_backup/id_rsa*`, you should be entering exactly what you have in your post, from within `.ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  key_backup  known_hosts

$ mv id_rsa* key_backup/

$ ls
key_backup  known_hosts

$ ls key_backup
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub
```